# How to write code to compare the drop down options in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

i have an UI where drop down are present with 20,50,100,500,1000 values.20 is the default value.I need to write the selenium java code to fetch the values and compare it.below is the code i have written.

```
  WebElement show = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='revtable_length']/label"));
        Select sel= new Select(show); 
        List <WebElement> option= sel.getOptions(); 
        //sAssert.assertEquals(show,"Show20501005001000 entries","retrieve table dropdown button is not present");
        for (int i= 0; i< option.size(); i++)![enter image description here][1]
        System.out.print((option.get(i)).getText());
```

but i am getting the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "label"
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-27 00:00:10'
System info: host: 'bionicps0000574', ip: '167.209.185.85', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_20'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Comment: Html code:
<label>
Show 
<select name="revtable_length" aria-controls="revtable">
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
<option value="500">500</option>
<option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
 entries
</label>
</div>

Comment: Please do not add code in comments - edit your post instead to include new information.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's wrong in your code is how you are getting the element.

this part seems that you are getting an element that has an id of "revtable_length"

```
WebElement show = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='revtable_length']/label"));
```

But base on the source code you posted the element is

try to change

```
WebElement show = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='revtable_length']/label"));
```

to

```
WebElement show = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@name='revtable_length']/label"));
```

or

```
WebElement show = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='revtable_length']"));
```

Hope this helps.

Try this one.

```
   WebElement show = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='revtable_length']"));
            Select sel= new Select(show); 
            List <WebElement> option= sel.getOptions(); 
            //sAssert.assertEquals(show,"Show20501005001000 entries","retrieve table dropdown button is not present");

            StringBuffer options = new StringBuffer();
            options.append("Show");
            for (int i= 0; i< option.size(); i++){
                options.append((option.get(i)).getText());
            }

            System.out.print(options);
            Assert.assertEquals(options.toString(),"Show20501005001000", "Retrieved value is not correct!");
```

Hope this is what exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks,It works but i need to print the Show and entries as well .
Like Show is present after <label> of HTML code and entries in  </select> entries </label.How i can print this along with the options.

Comment: do you want to print it like this?

Show 20
Show 50 and so on?

or get value and compare?

Comment: No.I want to print like: "Show20501005001000 entries"
and also i want to compare it by using assert command.How i can o it?
For this i need to save the Actual value and compare it with the expected value

Comment: It is not working.I am getting the below error:
java.lang.AssertionError: Retrieved value is correct expected [Show20501005001000] but found [Show20501005001000]
 at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
 at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:494)
 at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:123)

Comment: It works for me and its weird that it fails but it says that [Show20501005001000] but found [Show20501005001000] and those two are equal

Comment: Exactly,it confused me the most.It says [Show20501005001000] but found [Show20501005001000]  and both the result are same.But i dont know why it is failing.